# Creating a lambda function dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

Is there some way I could create a lambda function dynamically? For example,

```
f = lambda t : (1 + 32*t + 23*np.power(t,2) + 23*np.power(t,3) + 23*np.power(t,4))
```

in the above lambda function `f`, I want to increment the value of `t` in `23*np.power(t,2)` and want it to go until 467. So:

```
f = lambda t : (1 + 32*t + 23*np.power(t,2) + .. + 23*np.power(t,467))
```

Is there a way I could do this automatically?

Comment: `q+32*t+sum(23 * np.power(t,x) for x in range(2,468))`? its either goign to be an insanely high number or 0? mabye something sensible for t<0 - what good is it for?#

Comment: @PatrickArtner Will be a small number. I need to solve a polynomial equation that goes to inf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might you something like `f = lambda t : 1 + sum(23 * np.power(t, i) for i in range(1, 467))`. You can't use for loops or something like that, but simple expressions, function calls etc. you can

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: End range should be 468.

Answer (score 2):

The two parameters of `np.power` broadcast against each other.

```
def foo(t, p):
    return 1+32*t + np.sum(23*np.power(t,np.arange(*p)[:,None]), axis=0)
```

This is written to take a `t` array, and a power range:

```
In [445]: foo(np.linspace(0,1,11),(2,4))                                                              
Out[445]: 
array([ 1.   ,  4.453,  8.504, 13.291, 18.952, 25.625, 33.448, 42.559,
       53.096, 65.197, 79.   ])
In [446]: foo(np.linspace(0,1,11),(2,468))                                                            
Out[446]: 
array([1.00000000e+00, 4.45555556e+00, 8.55000000e+00, 1.35571429e+01,
       1.99333333e+01, 2.85000000e+01, 4.09000000e+01, 6.09666667e+01,
       1.00200000e+02, 2.16100000e+02, 1.07510000e+04])
```

This version gives the caller more control:

```
def foo(t, p, axis=0):
    return 1+32*t + np.sum(23*np.power(t,p), axis=axis)
```

e.g. a 2d `t` array (but you have to understand broadcasting well):

```
In [449]: foo(np.linspace(0,1,10).reshape(2,5),np.arange(2,468)[:,None,None])                         
Out[449]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 4.87500000e+00, 9.57142857e+00, 1.55000000e+01,
        2.34000000e+01],
       [3.47500000e+01, 5.30000000e+01, 8.85000000e+01, 1.93000000e+02,
        1.07510000e+04]])
```